# Persist ASP.NET Core auth cookies between docker image launches

Tags: cookies, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

Each time a Docker image containing a .NET Core MVC web application starts up, all authentication cookies are invalidated, presumably due to a fresh machine key (which is used when signing the cookies) being generated.

This could traditionally be set via the `<machineKey/>` element in the `web.config` of a .NET app.

[This link](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/240) suggests that the `DataProtection` package would fit the bill, but the package seems to require the full fat framework.

What would be the correct way to ensure that every time a Docker image restarts it doesn't invalidate existing auth cookies?

Comment: Are cookies invalidate or are sessions invalidated? If sessions, are you keeping session state in process or externally?

Comment: Look at this blog post about ASP.NET Core 1.1 preview1 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/ near the end of it there is a new feature about using DataProtection with Redis or Azure Storage. However, ASP.NET Core 1.1 is still a preview version and is expected to be released Q4 2016 / Q1 2017

Comment: Additionally, both current and 1.1 DataProtection does support netstandard, see https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/project.json

Comment: Wording: The cookies are client side. They are encrypted on the server. If the private key changes, previously generated cookies can't get decrypted anymore. So it's about keeping the private key.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Running on IIS Express on my development machine, logins persist through a machine restart. The session is not persisted anywhere, so I assume this must be a key/cookie signing issue.

Comment: @Tseng You're right, it's just the `DataProtection.SystemWeb` package that is full fat only, and considering its purpose that makes sense.

Comment: The key is stored on disk and therefore persisted over machine restarts. It's fairly well documented. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html

Comment: Is `DataProtection` always used then @thoean? The behaviour I describe above was happening before I added the package to my project.

Comment: I don't know all details, but I assume that package might have been referenced through another package. For example Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies references it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @thoean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put the keys for data protection into a persistent and shareable location.

If you're on AWS, [AspNetCore.DataProtection.Aws](https://github.com/hotchkj/AspNetCore.DataProtection.Aws) allows to put the keyring on S3 with just a few lines of configuration code. Additionally you can leverage AWS KMS to encrypt the keys, which is especially useful to achieve consistent encryption algorithms, allowing to reuse the same key accross different operating systems which have different default encryption algorithms. The KMS option is also part of the same library.

If you're on another platform than AWS, you'll need another library or mount a shared drive. But the concept of sharing the same location for the keys remains the same.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'm really looking for a way to put this directly into the web application though, rather than rely on an external platform. In an ideal world I would just specify the machine/decryption keys in a configuration file.

Comment: You can do this as well by manually placing a key into the directory you specify. Note that you'll need to manage renewal in case your services don't get redeployed before the expiration period.